# Renaming multiples files with .bat

Tags: batch-file

I've been looking for a .bat file in Windows 7 that given a name and a file directory, renames all of the files in that directory to the name that the user pass concatenated to a number that goes from 0 to 9. 
For example:
Let's say that i have a directory with two files a.txt and b.txt, i want to change their names to documentX.txt (X being a number from 0 to 9), so at the end the script will change the names to document1.txt and document2.txt

i have tried something like this but without sucess:

```
    @echo off
    @set a=1
    @set pref=hola

    for /D %%f in (C:\*.txt) 
     do 
     rename *.txt %pref%%a%
     @set /A a = %a%+1
```

Answer (score 1):

The FOR command cannot span multiple lines unless you use parentheses or line continuation `^`. The first opening parenthesis must be on the same line as the IN and the 2nd on the same line as the DO.

You cannot use normal expansion within a parenthesised block of code that also sets the value because the expansion occurs at parse time and the entire block is parsed at once. So the value will be the value that existed before you set it! The solution is to use delayed expansion. That occurs when the line is executed. It must be enabled with `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`.

Delayed expansion causes a problem because `!` is valid within a file name and FOR variable expansion will be corrupted if it contains `!` while delayed expansion is enabled. The solution is to toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

You want a simple FOR without any options. The `/D` option looks for directories instead of files.

You do not need to expand numeric variables within a `SET /A` statement.

One last thing - no need for `@` after you use `ECHO OFF`.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "n=0"
set "pref=document"

for %%F in (c:\*.txt) do (
  set "file=%%F"
  set /a n+=1
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!file!" "%pref%!n!.txt"
  endlocal
)
```

There is a simpler way to accomplish the task. Use `DIR /B` to list all the `.txt` files and pipe the results to `FINSTDR /N "^"`. The FINDSTR will match all files and will prefix each value with a sequential number followed by a colon. Use FOR /F to parse the result into the number and the file name so you can then RENAME.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "pref=document"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt^|findstr /n "^"') do (
  ren "%%B" "%pref%%%A.txt"
)
```

Comment: If your question has been answered to your satisfaction then you should accept the answer by clicking on the check mark near the upper left corner of the answer. That action lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 reputation, and awards the answer provider 15 rep points. Only 1 answer can be accepted. Once you reach 15 rep points you will have the privilege to up vote answers as well. You can up vote as many answers as you find useful, even answers to other people's questions. An up vote awards the answer provider 10 points.